# Liquid: Capture String in a space Following a "trigger string" possible?

Tags: arrays, string, liquid, capture

Instead of doing this below in liquid when I might not even know all the possible colors that could exist, could I somehow just capture the full next row following "Color:" so that "Color:" is the triggertag that starts the capture and next row break is the trigger that decides when the capturing should stop?

And could I also use another word as the trigger of the end capture, for example if I know that I always want to capture what is between the only `<strong>` and `</strong>` tag in a description?

```
{% if product.description contains 'Color:' %}
{% if product.description contains 'Color: Red'%}{% assign TheColor = "Red" %}{% endif %} 
{% if product.description contains 'Color: Yellow'%}{% assign TheColor = "Yellow" %}{% endif %} 
{% if product.description contains 'Color: Ocean Blue'%}{% assign TheColor  = "Ocean Blue" %}{% endif %}  
{% if product.description contains 'Color: Light Blue'%}{% assign TheColor = "Ocean Blue" %}{% endif %} 
{% if product.description contains 'Color: Blue'%}{% assign TheColor = "Blue" %}{% endif %} 
{% if product.description contains 'Color: Black & white'%}{% assign TheColor = "Black & white" %}{% endif %} 
{% endif %}
```

I've been googling for hours for something like this, I know I did it somehow in Asp Classic 10 years ago with a long code, but I figure it should be super simple in Liquid?

I don't have formal liquid education (which I probably share with many others who find this through searches) so a simple example in code rather than a "tech hint" or "clue" would be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a hacky way to get just the colour, though it doesn't feel super reliable:

```
{% assign color = product.description | split: "Color: " %}
{{ color | last }}
```

This splits the description into an array. Everything before `Color:`is the first element, and everything after `Color:` is the second element. In our output we just print the second element.

This won't work right if there's anything else after the color declaration in your product description.

Comment: Follow-up: There's  probably a better way to do this. I assume you're using Shopify — if so you can give a product variants and record the color as one of the variant options, then use Liquid's `{{ variant | option1 }}` to get the value of the first option, assuming `color` is the first option.

Here are some docs about using Liquid with variants: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/variant

Comment: Thank you!!, there will be information following it, but your first solution would work if there was a way to truncate this text at the next row break or split it again (so truncating at the first row break of the second element). Or capturing the first row of the second element that you isolated.Is that possible in some way?

Comment: I am using shopify, but the text in the description is just pasted from another site and I am then hoping that I can pick up the information from there and never have to write it into the variants manual and all that, so option two would not work unfortunately, since the information in the description is not in the shopify system.